# Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=0$, the series $\sum\frac{a_n}{n^2}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Being $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=0$ then i can suppose that $a_n$ is bounded, otherwise there would not be a limit. Therefore the series $\sum\frac{a_n}{n^2}$ can be rewritten as $\sum{a_n\frac{1}{n^2}}$ and so as $a_n$ is bounded and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ convergent, then $\sum\frac{a_n}{n^2}$ is convergent!

That's nice? Am i wrong?

Comment: The example $a_n = n/\log n$ will certainly not going to agree with you...

Comment: $a_n$ may not be bounded. The argument is wrong. It may or may not converge. There are examples in both cases.

Comment: ok! i got it. i was afraid of this.

Comment: but then i lost my only argument hehehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the part

> Being $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=0$ then i can suppose that $a_n$ is bounded, otherwise there would not be a limit.

In this context, the limit of $a_n/n$ can be zero when $a_n$ goes to infinity slowly, for example $a_n=\log n$. 
Therefore, your approach only works if the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded, but it is not guaranteed by the assumptions.

The problem can be rephrased in the following way: if $\left(\epsilon_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}  $ is a sequence of real numbers which converges to $0$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{ +\infty}\epsilon_n /n$ converges.

- There are examples of sequence $\left(\epsilon_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converging to $0$ such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{ +\infty}\epsilon_n /n$ converges, like $\epsilon_n:=1/n$.
- There are examples of sequence $\left(\epsilon_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converging to $0$ such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{ +\infty}\epsilon_n /n$ diverges, like $\epsilon_n:=1/\log n$ (the keyword is Bertrand series).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider
$$
a_n=\frac{n}{\log(n)}
$$
and use the [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) to check the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^2}
$$